# Are the points on a unit circle a countable set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, circles, cardinals

I was watching this video: https://youtu.be/s86-Z-CbaHA

Near 4:10, he says that all the real numbers between 0 and 1 are uncountable. But near 8:38, he says that all the points on that circle are countable because they can be in one-to-one correspondence with natural numbers. But, isn't that just another way of saying that all the real numbers between 0 to 2pi are countable? Because , on a unit circle, each point can also correspond to one real number between  0 and 2pi. So, how can that be countable?

Comment: I have not watched the video, and won't. You have either misquoted what's there, or the video is wrong, as your argument shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't hear any claims about circles around 6:38.

At 8:50 the video does say "this set [of points on the unit circle] is never ending but countable". But it doesn't claim that the set it speaks about consists of *all* points on the unit circle, and it doesn't.

Comment: I thought all the points could obviously be reached that way. And I meant 8:38

Comment: @RyderRude: One point that obviously _can't_ be reached is the point one radian _before_ the starting point (because if it could be reached, the sequence would repeat).

Answer (score 1):

The numbers on the unit circle with *finite order* are countable, i.e. all complex numbers $z$ such that there is a natural number $n$ with $z^n=1$. Geometrically these points correspond to all points on the unit circle such that there is a regular $n$-gon with that point and the point $(1,0)$ as a vertex  and the point $(0,0)$ as its center (not every point has this property).

The set of *all* points of the unit circle is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

The points on the unit circle are in one to one correspondence with real numbers so they are not countable . 
On the other hand the set of all $n^{th} $ roots of unity is a countable subset of the unit circle as claimed in videos.